# Unable to draw polygon in gmap.net wpf

Tags: wpf, polygon, gmap.net

I am using gmap.net for my wpf application but i am unable to draw polygon in wpf. I found lot of tutorials of windows form for polygon and all those are working fine. But I didn't find any solution of wpf please help me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for make polygon

```
        //Declare List for pointlatlang
        List<PointLatLng> pointlatlang = new List<PointLatLng>();
        pointlatlang.Add(new PointLatLng(-6.9143433, 107.6014166));
        pointlatlang.Add(new PointLatLng(-6.9143416, 107.6013700));

        //Declare polygon in gmap
        GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(pointlatlang);
        mymap.RegenerateShape(polygon);
        //setting line style
        (polygon.Shape as Path).Stroke = Brushes.DarkBlue;
        (polygon.Shape as Path).StrokeThickness = 1.5;
        (polygon.Shape as Path).Effect = null;
        //To add polygon in gmap
        mymap.Markers.Add(polygon);
```

Comment: @alfradias Why there is a null reference exception in 5th last line?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may have been a typo, but in line 7:
**polygon.RegenerateShape(mymap);**

You should have instead:
**mymap.RegenerateShape(polygon);**

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Declare List for pointlatlang
    List<PointLatLng> pointlatlang = new List<PointLatLng>();
    pointlatlang.Add(new PointLatLng(-6.9143433, 107.6014166));
    pointlatlang.Add(new PointLatLng(-6.9143416, 107.6013700));

    //Declare polygon in gmap
    GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(pointlatlang);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) { Opacity=0.5};
    path.StrokeThickness = 1.5;
    path.Stroke = Brushes.DarkBlue;
    path.Effect = null;
    
    polygon.Shape = path;

    //To add polygon in gmap
    mymap.Markers.Add(polygon);
```

Answer (score 0):

although i didn't find any solution of my problem but i found another alternative way to solve it. I have integrated windows form control of Gmap.net in WPF applications and used gmap.net dll for windows form.